# Fetching dynamically created text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textarea in which I put HTML code, and then dynamically preview this HTML inside the `preview` div:

```
<div id="preview">
</div>

<textarea id="fooBar">
   <div style="background-color:green;"></div>
</textarea>
```

jQuery code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var html = $('#fooBar').text();
    $('#preview').html(html);
    $('#fooBar').on('keyup', function() {
        var html = $(this).text();
        $('#preview').html(html);
    });
});
```

The problem is that changing HTML code doesn't do nothing. Console log on html variable always shows the same initial content, it's not being changed.

How do I solve this, and why is that so?

Answer (score 2):

Just change the text() to val().

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var html = $('#fooBar').text();
    $('#preview').html(html);
    $('#fooBar').on('keyup', function() {
        var html = $(this).val();
        $('#preview').html(html);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use val() instead of text(). val() is used for form elements like textarea in your case, whereas text() is HTML elements. I hope this will work

```
<div id="preview"></div>
<textarea id="fooBar">
       <div style="background-color:green;"></div>
    </textarea>    


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var html = $('#fooBar').val();
    $('#preview').html(html);
    $('#fooBar').on('keyup', function() {
        var html = $(this).val();
        $('#preview').html(html);
    });
});
```